# Is there a replacement for the old facebook prompt_feed.php?

Tags: facebook, url, share

I used to be able to construct a link like this:

http://www.facebook.com/connect/prompt_feed.php?message=hello

It would go to the page it currently does (click on the link to see) but it used to pre-populate the text field with the value of the `message` parameter. Now the text field is empty.

I suppose facebook changed this functionality, but is there a replacement that provides the same functionality? Note that I do not want to have to authenticate the user or connect them to an app. I am looking for a simple url that will just open a new window with a status message pre-populated so the user can just click "Share" (exactly how this prompt_feed.php used to work). Anybody know of a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

What about the feed dialog?
See here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/
**Update:** Ok, now I see that the user must have already authorized the app : [
**Update 2:** This isn't either a full replacement but an alternative - you could use the sharer php
http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=yoursite.com&t=yourtitle
In that case yoursite.com should contain og meta tags. It does not prefill the message though : [

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but (unfortunately) the pre-filled status message is the only part I need.